# Change Flow button label from 'Next' to 'Finish' in VisualForce page

Tags: visualforce, visual-workflow, flow

I have the following VisualForce page for my Flow Information_Updated_Case_Comment

```
<apex:page standardController="Case">
 <flow:interview name="Information_Updated_Case_Comment" finishLocation="/{!Case.Id}" buttonLocation="top">
      <apex:param name="var_CaseId" value="{!Case.Id}"/>
 </flow:interview>
</apex:page>
```

I now want to change the name / label of the button on the page from the Next button to the Finish button (but not the functionality - it already *finishes* the flow).

I've found [this](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_flows_customize_runtime_ui.htm) guide which lists the class that I need to use. But I can't figure out how to implement the change - where I need to include FlowFinishBtn in order to override the standard button?

Answer (score 3):

add this script to change the finish button and change the variable and value to change the other buttons

```
< script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"/ >

<script type="text/javascript" >
   (function ($) {
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("input.FlowFinishBtn").attr("value","Finish");
    });
   })(jQuery.noConflict(true))  
  } 
  < /script >
```